# Error in formating of XML string with CDATA

Tags: asp.net, xml, stored-procedures, cdata

I get this error "Start tag on line 1 does not match the end tag of 'document'".

```
    string rawXml = "<?xml version='1.0' ?>" +
        "<document>" +
            "<![CDATA[" +
                "<topic>" +
                   "My test" +
                "</topic>" +
            "]]>" +
        "</document>";
```

Error occurres when I try to execute a stored procedure which send this xml as a parameter.

```
    var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(rawXml);

    DataResultXElement drx = ss.xelem_Query(string.Format("exec Topic_Update '{0}', '{1}'", sessionId, xmlDoc.InnerXml));
```

If I remove  it works, but I need CDATE to store data properly in the database.

Should I format the string differently? Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't be using a string at all!

Comment: Thank you for your comment but what about solution? How can I send this XML-data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do not use string manipulation to construct XML documents.
2. Do not use string manipulation to construct SQL queries.

Do this instead:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb))
using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(sw))
{
    xw.WriteStartElement("document");
    xw.WriteCData("<topic>My test </topic>");
    xw.WriteEndElement();
}

XDocument result = new XDocument();
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Topic_Update", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("SessionID", sessionId);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("XmlText", sb.ToString());
    using (XmlReader xr = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader())
    {
        result.Load(xr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation! But why do I get this error? "Start tag on line 1 does not match the end tag of 'document'". Because the XMl is bad formatted? Or I should not use strings to construct SQL?

Comment: I think it's happening because you're using `string.Format` to construct your SQL.  The XML contains apostrophes, and the SQL string uses apostrophes to delimit parameters.  This is one of the many, many reasons to use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things:

- The parsing of your `rawXml` (i.e. constructing the `XmlDocument` instance) is completely superfluous.
- You must have made some typo in the raw XML. What you provided looks like a perfectly valid XML (actually passes W3C's validation).
- Don't construct a SQL query using `String.Format`. Use SQL query parameters instead. The reason is this way you end-up with an invalid SQL statement and also open the door for SQL-injection attacks.